# Can a person bring a translator to the driving test in Arkansas?

Tags: driving

My dad wants to get a drivers licence . He passed the written test. But his English listening is not perfect. We are from India btw.

So, may I legally be at the back seat of the car just in case he does not understand something ?

I know one can do this in Illinois. PLEASE do not tell me to call to the dmv and ask them. I am looking for a legal document online that would either allow it or disallow it (WRITTEN REFERENCE ONLY)

Comment: Sorry, you want us to google something for you? You can't do this yourself because ...

Comment: i did i googled yahooed whatever  . i could not find anything . is there any OFFICIAL LEGAL REFERENCE that either allows or disallows a translator . What does the law say about it ? Are there any lawyer at this website ?

Comment: @user3191304 Are there any lawyers on this website? Everyone is a lawyer here! Everyone on the Internet is a lawyer! But really, a lawyer is not the person who can answer this question. A lawyer is the person you call when you are refused a translator which in turn prevents you from obtaining a drivers license. The ACLU is representing some guy somewhere against the DMV for failing to provide a foreign language test. Something about federal funding and non English speakers. I don't think you'll find an official up or down answer on this one. At least not on the Internet.

Comment: @jqning thank you very much. this answers my question. For all other people who are interested . Here is the short answer : `Title VI of the Civil Rights Act of 1964 requires agencies receiving federal funding to provide individuals with limited English proficiency meaningful access to agency programs and services`

Comment: Keep in mind that they may have flexibility in how that provide access, for example it might not be you in the car. Also, don't assume all DMVs get federal funding. Perhaps they do? I don't know.

Comment: A translator, probably yes. You, who could be quite likely to help him pass his test, probably no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `yes` : any dmv must provide a translator, or at least let a person bring a translator . Here is a reference to a legal source

```
        Title VI of the Civil Rights Act of 1964 requires agencies 
        receiving federal funding to provide individuals with
        limited English proficiency meaningful access to 
        agency programs and services.
```

Official link is [here](http://www.justice.gov/crt/title-vi-civil-rights-act-1964-42-usc-i-2000d-et-seq)